# How to put the column entry value matching the row number in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have generated random data like this.

```
data <- replicate(10,sample(0:9,10,rep=FALSE))
ind <- which(data %in% sample(data, 5))
#now replace those indices in data with NA
data[ind]<-NA
#here is our vector with 15 random NAs 
data = as.data.frame(data)
rownames(data) = 1:10
colnames(data) = 1:10
data
```

which results in a data frame like this. How can I reorder the entry value such that if the entry is numeric, then the value will be placed in a (row number - 1), and NA will be put in any rows where there is no value matching the (row number -1). The data I want, for example, the first column, should look like this
[image: data].

How can I do this? I have no clue at all. We can order decreasing or increasing and put NA in the last order, but that is not what I want.

[image: dataframe]

Comment: Not clear about the logic you want to apply.  Do you want to subtract the row number with 1

Comment: Perhaps `data %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ lag(.x[match(row_number(), .x)])))`

Comment: @akrun Since the entries are 0-9 but the row numbers are 0 to 10 so row number minus 1

Answer (score 1):

You can make a helper function to assign values to indices at (values + 1), then apply the function over all columns:

```
fx <- function(x) {
  vals <- x[!is.na(x)]
  pos <- vals + 1
  out <- rep(NA, length(x))
  out[pos] <- vals
  out
}

as.data.frame(sapply(data, fx))
```

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1  NA  0 NA  0  0  0  0 NA  0  0
2  NA NA NA  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA
3   2 NA  2  2 NA NA NA NA  2 NA
4   3 NA  3  3 NA NA  3 NA  3  3
5   4  4  4  4 NA  4 NA  4  4 NA
6   5  5 NA  5 NA NA  5  5  5 NA
7  NA  6  6 NA  6 NA NA  6 NA NA
8   7 NA  7  7 NA  7  7 NA NA  7
9  NA NA NA NA  8  8  8  8  8  8
10  9  9 NA NA  9 NA NA  9 NA  9
```

Starting data:

```
set.seed(13)

data <- replicate(10, sample(
  c(0:9, rep(NA, 10)), 
  10, 
  replace = FALSE
))
data <- as.data.frame(data)
colnames(data) <- 1:10
data
```

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1   2 NA NA  2 NA NA  0 NA  3  7
2   4 NA NA  4 NA NA NA NA  2  9
3   9  9 NA  3  9  4 NA  6  4  0
4  NA NA NA  1  6 NA NA  4 NA NA
5   5  6  3  0 NA NA  5  8  8 NA
6  NA NA  7 NA NA NA  7 NA  5  3
7   3  4  6 NA  1  0 NA  5 NA NA
8  NA NA NA  7  0  7 NA NA  0 NA
9  NA  0  4 NA  8  8  8  9 NA  8
10  7  5  2  5 NA NA  3 NA NA NA
```

Comment: The result you got (the order) is what I want, but each column should have different values since it is randomly generated entries.

Comment: @MKHuda that’s because the code you provided creates the same values in every column. Look at your example data — you have the same values (1,2,3,4,7) in every column, just in a different order.

Comment: I edited my example data to have different values in each column - the same code still works.